# The log file for LXDE in /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi is taking up almost my entire SD card

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, lxde

I have a 32Gb SD card on a Pi4 4gb, But almost all (23Gb) the available Flash memory is being taken up by the LXDE log file [run.log] located in /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi - I have deleted this file numerous times, but it quickly gets regenerated after a reboot. How do I stop this happening? I use my Pi exclusively as a file/web server. Other than Apache, the pi is a bare-bones install. This only seems to have started after I installed Plex out of curiosity. I removed Plex almost straight away, as I found it unsuitable for my needs. I understand that LXDE is used for the desktop environment, but what could be using this much memory? I can't onpen the log file, as the pi doesn't have the ram available to cache it in memory. So I can't look in there to see what is taking up the space.[image: My Drive]

Comment: Just delete it!

Comment: I have, several times. It just keeps coming back. It's also stopping my server from working. I can't transfer files remotely to the server because there is no space on the SD card for the transfer. It's annoying and shouldn't be happening.

Comment: After you delete it you should be able to examine it. If you don't want it just link to `/dev/null`. There is nothing of interest to log!